# why can not build godef.go?

Tags: github, go

> first I pull the soure code or zipfile, They both show the same error log like this when I go build godef.go.

```
go build godef.go
# command-line-arguments
.\godef.go:55: undefined: acmeFile
.\godef.go:59: undefined: acmeCurrentFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Building a single Go file from a multi-file Go package or command makes no sense. Build all the files. For example,

```
$ go build godef.go acme.go doc.go
```

or

```
$ go build *.go
```

Or, simply build the package or command

```
$ go build github.com/rogpeppe/godef
```

Why are you using `go build` instead of `go install`?

Why did you "pull the soure [sic] code or zipfile"? Use `go get`, which does a `go install` for you, for example,

```
$ go get -v -u github.com/rogpeppe/godef
github.com/rogpeppe/godef (download)
github.com/rogpeppe/godef/vendor/9fans.net/go/plan9
github.com/rogpeppe/godef/go/token
github.com/rogpeppe/godef/go/scanner
github.com/rogpeppe/godef/go/ast
github.com/rogpeppe/godef/vendor/9fans.net/go/plan9/client
github.com/rogpeppe/godef/vendor/9fans.net/go/acme
github.com/rogpeppe/godef/go/parser
github.com/rogpeppe/godef/go/printer
github.com/rogpeppe/godef/go/types
github.com/rogpeppe/godef
```

Reference:

[Command go](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)